# checkbox list to generate one textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

So i have this checkbox list and im trying to generate a textbox when the MISC checkbox is checked.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chbxEquipmnt" runat="server"RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ValidationGroup="Equipment" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chbxEquipmnt_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Laptop">Laptop</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value=" Label Printer">Label Printer</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Printer">Printer</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Fax Line">Fax Line</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="PC">PC</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MFD">MFD</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Phone Line">Phone Line</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Misc">Misc</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

ON my Cs page I have.........

```
protected void chbxEquipmnt_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chbxEquipmnt.SelectedValue == "Misc")
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "txtMiscCheckBox";
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
}
```

debugging i have tried with Postback which continuously on returns the first check box that was checked...for example i checked laptop instead of Misc first, the value in the debugger always show me laptop. Im not sure if a simple loop to go thru the all the button clicks would help.....I'm fresh out of school and this is a career change for me so thanks for the patience

Comment: where is the AutoPostBack prop ? this wont work like this

Comment: sorry i pasted a version without it...ill put it back in checkbox list now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the approach: don't create the Textbox at run time.

Have it created at design time, hide it by default (Visible property), then show it when `Misc` option is selected.

You will run into less issues that way. Creating controls in runtime require some extra effort : dealing with `ViewState`, re-creating the control on `PostBack`, etc.

Comment: this is the route im going, now if i could only get the textbox exactly where i want it..